# Does Jquery Ajax command use CORS?

Tags: ajax

Does that mean that the server I'm doing an ajax request from needs to support CORS. So therefore, it needs a **header** that specifies "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *"

??

Comment: jQuery just uses the browser's XMLHttpRequest. It's subject to the same restrictions as any other use of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example`- more secure as it will only accept from domains you specify